# Quitar espacio en blanco etiqueta <pre>

Tags: html, css, email, html-correo

Estoy creando un archivo `html` para una firma de correo en `Thunderbird` y me pasaron un texto entre etiquetas `<pre>` que no consigo colocar, ya que me aparece alineado a la derecha en vez de estar alineado a la izquierda contra el logo, dejando un espacio vacío.

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 40px;" valign="top" >
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 1px; ">
            <img src="http://logo.com/logo.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 80px; width: 80px;">
        </td>

        <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
          <div style="display: flex; align-items: flex-start;">
            <pre style="margin: 0; text-align: left; margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0;">
              _______________________________
        
              <b>Nombre Apellido Apellido2</b>
              Puesto en la Empresa
              nombre.apellido@empresa.com
        
              Empresa
              <a href="https://www.empresa.com" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">www.empresa.com</a>
              _______________________________
            </pre>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola b1nar10, he probado tu código, coloca la imagen pegada al marco izquierdo, y pegada a este, el texto, es lo que querías?.

Comment: Quiero pegar el texto de dentro de las etiquetas <pre> a la izquierda, en el cuadro del logo.

Comment: dentro del cuadro del logo?.

Comment: Ya encontré el problema, la etiqueta <pre> mantiene el formato y por más que intentaba cambiarla desde CSS era imposible, al final fue tan fácil como pegarla a la izquierda y sacar todos los espacios que tenia. Muchas Gracias de todas Maneras!

Comment: @b1nar10 Aunque parezca una tontería, podrías poner lo que has hecho como respuesta y así, si alguien más tiene un problema similar, podrá encontrar la solución. Es totalmente correcto responder tus propias preguntas :)

Answer (score 2):

La solución a tu problema es modificar la propiedad [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) del `<pre>` y establecerla a `pre-line`

La siguiente tabla resume el comportamiento de los diversos valores de `white-space`:

|  | Nuevas líneas | Espacios y tabulaciones | Ajuste de texto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| normal | Contraer | Contraer | Ajustar |
| nowrap | Contraer | Contraer | No ajustar |
| pre | Preservar | Preservar | No ajustar |
| pre-wrap | Preservar | Preservar | Ajustar |
| pre-line | Preservar | Contraer | Ajustar |

#### Ejemplo:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 40px;" valign="top">
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 1px; ">
      <img src="http://logo.com/logo.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 80px; width: 80px;">
    </td>

    <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
      <div style="display: flex; align-items: flex-start;">
        <pre style="margin: 0; text-align: left; margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0; white-space: pre-line;">
              _______________________________
        
              <b>Nombre Apellido Apellido2</b>
              Puesto en la Empresa
              nombre.apellido@empresa.com
        
              Empresa
              <a href="https://www.empresa.com" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">www.empresa.com</a>
              _______________________________
            </pre>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```